# How to remove mongodb and the related files completely from the system?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have started installing mongoDB, got struck like anything.

I can understand the mongoDB is not running even though it shows like mongo auto and a log file. I have deleted almost all the folders and i ran almost all the commands i have seen on net.

I need the commands which removes the mongodb completely from my system.I cannot understand what's happening with the mongodb.

Finally I have decided to remove it completely(not even a single instance of mongo).

provide me the best commands which might help me.

Comment: [**Related**](http://askubuntu.com/a/497144)

Comment: Still there are some mongo files in my system and something is running when i enter mongo command in terminal. So i want to remove completely the mongo*. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might help for Mongo 3.0

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

and for Mongo 2.6

https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

At the bottom of the page are instructions to remove all files.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "answer" by checking it.

Comment: How to do the same in windows

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Yes I tried the same to solve the issue I got and reinstalled but still ran the same problem. Please look into this link and if possible please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267805/mongodb-system-error-1067-while-stopping-a-windows-service